# How to prevent a react component remount because of wrapper added/removed

Tags: reactjs

Consider the following example:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ id }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("mounted", id);
  }, []);

  return null;
};

const App = () => {
  const [outside, setOutside] = useState(false);

  const component = <SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" />;
  const otherComponent = <SomeComponent id="wontrerender" key="wontrerender" />;

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOutside((outside) => {
      console.log("setting", outside ? "outside" : "inside");
      return !outside;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>trigger</button>
      {outside ? component : <div>{component}</div>}
      {otherComponent}
    </div>
  );
};
```

And [playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-ysnoi?file=/index.js:0-826).

I was expecting that the component (`SomeComponent` in this case) won't remount just because it's wrapped in an another component (`div` in this case) - but only update. I would like to prevent this from happening.

The above example shows that if you click the button, it will make `willrerender` remount, while `wontrerender` won't rerender.

How could I do that the component "stays" the same (doesn't remount, keeps state) regardless of its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible. This just isn't how React works.

React renders all the JSX to a virtual DOM, then compares to the previously rendered DOM, and then mounts/unmounts as necessary from there.

```
 <SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" />;
```

desugars to:

```
React.createElement(SomeComponent, { id: "willrerender", key: "willrerender" });
```

Note that your functional component is just passed to React, along with the props. I'm fairly sure that your component is *not* fully rendered at this point. Instead React just keeps the component function and its props in the virtual DOM.

Then *after* everything is rendered and taken its spot in that virtual DOM, React crawls the freshly new tree and mounts/unmounts things as necessary where they differ from the previous render of the virtual DOM.

And state is kept at a particular location in this virtual DOM. So if you change the path to that component, you make it a new "instance" of that component*.

This all means that:

```
const const component = <SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" />;

return <>
  <div>{component}</div>
  <div>{component}</div>
  <div>{component}</div>
</>
```

Is actually indistinguishable from:

```
return <>
  <div><SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" /></div>
  <div><SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" /></div>
  <div><SomeComponent id="willrerender" key="willrerender" /></div>
</>
```

---

React is declarative. That means show it how you want the page to look, and then let React manage the details to comply. So for the most part, managing when a component mounts/unmounts should not be your responsibility.

---

* The exception here is siblings differentiated by keys. This is one common case that React knows it needs to handle. If you change the order of items, the `key` helps react keep track of which component got moved where. But this *only* works for siblings of a node. If you move the component vertically in the tree there is nothing in React that will tell React the *identity* of a component.